# React Native createBottomTabNavigator with spacing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I've been trying to figure this out for awhile now.

Im wondering if its possible to achieve to add spacing between the side and bottom of the nav bar, something similar to the below mock:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using `react-navigation` or `react-native-navigation`?

Comment: using react-navigation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with styles easily.

```
const DEVICE_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

tabBarOptions: {
  activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  labelStyle: {
    fontSize: 12,
  },
  style: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    marginLeft:20, // Use margins as you required
    marginRight:20,
    marginBottom:20,
    width: DEVICE_WIDTH - 40, // Or using a percentage as required
    borderRadius:25,
  },
}
```

Or you can use an already reacted component as the Tab Navigator.

```
const tab = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
    tabBarComponent: props =>
      <Component
        style={{ //Styles //}}
      />,
  },
);
```

Comment: Ahhh thanks for that, so the grey area in the picture is the background and the 'bottom nav bar' is essentially a floating nav bar, i want to make it into like a 3d looking, how do i apply box-shadow, i tried doing boxShadow

Comment: Check this github issue. You can learn how to use shadows there. https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/709